# How to make pipeline fail when a error is outputted from java compiler

Tags: java, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Im using azure pipelines to compile all my java programs, but when a program doesn't compile, it throws an error on the bash, but dosent fail the pipeline. the yaml file is https://github.com/gitcloneguy/Java-Projects/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bash task with option failOnStderr.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops